# Concat multiple line in one

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

I'm working with MS Sql Server 2008,
I have the following table

```
----------------
Uid | Alias |
--------------- |
1 | Pierre |
1 | Patrick |
1 | Jean |
2 | Alice |
2 | Diana |
```

and I want to display it in this manner:

```
------------------------|
Uid | Alias |
------------------------|
1 | Pierre Patrick Jean|
2 | Alice Diana |
```

Any idea will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select b.Uid,
    (select a.Alias +' ' from TableName a WHERE a.Uid=b.Uid group by a.Alias FOR XML PATH(''))as Names
from TableName b
group by b.Uid
```